# mysql connection with vb6

Tags: mysql, database, vb6

i m using vb6 for connecting with mysql

How to get the details for Server because in the given example the Server is assigned to HOST so how do i know that what value i have to assign there ???

```
    Set database_connection = New ADODB.Connection
    database_connection.ConnectionString = _
    "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=HOST; " & _
    "Database=SCHEMA; " & _
    "User=USER; " & _
    "Password=PASSWORD; " & _
    "Option=3;"
    database_connection.Open
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- HOST : the IP or network name of the server where your database is stored
- SCHEMA : the name of your database
- USER : the user connecting to the database
- PASSWORD : the password

If you don't know on which server your database is stored, there's no way we can know it better than you.

According to your comment, your database is on the machine where your code gets executed. Then HOST = `localhost`

Comment: i m not connecting with any network and the database is in my system only 

suppose my destination of database is something like 

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1 
then i have to assign that in HOST ???